# My bootstrap website images are not showing correctly on mobile devices after uploading to the server

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, mobile-website

I made this website with bootstrao- [andamios.cl](http://andamios.cl)
It is perfect on desktop. I have checked it through chrome's different viewport. it works fine as a full responsive website but when i uploaded it to the server and visited the site with iphone and ipad. some images were stretched and some were not showing. But on Android devices, i can say almost fine (Images were showing ) but not perfect. 
On PC, it is perfect.
I also saw a horizontal scroll bar after finishing the project. I mean a some blank space on the right side of page.

I mostly used container and container-fluid.
I also used this meta tag-

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

I am not sure what is causing this. Thanks for your help.

I am adding one of the section which image is not showing on iphone and ipad.

```
#banner {
    height: 100%;
    background: url('/Images/3.jpg')fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: your url does not work

Comment: o sorry. it should be andamios.cl

Comment: @JoostS Can you take a look at my website now please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The horizontal scrollbar is your footer form flying in from the right. It should be wrapped in a container with overflow hidden. That will solve it.

I do not see any stretched images (but I have no iOS to check). Sorry for that.

Comment: i resolve the issue with ios by this--          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36686654/fixed-background-images-disappear-on-iphone-ipad

Comment: i already added the footer in a container fluid but i added the overflow: hidden as you said @joostS but it did not resolve the issue of white space on the right

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue of white space by adding overflow-x: hidden to the body