# Perfect Full Page Background Image not Working on Mobile

Tags: html, css, background-image, cover

The Perfect Full Page Background Image is not working correctly on mobile...

Can you please help me adjust the CSS/HTML code below?

**Previewing in Chrome:**

[image]

**Live on iPhone 7Plus:**

[image]

Notice how the background image is skewed, distorted, and blurry?
Why does it look like this live, but not in the preview mode?

I have this meta code in the doc as well:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

**The CSS:**

```
.MSL-Splash-Section {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0px 20px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #FFF url(https://sephora.csod.com/clientimg/sephora/welcome/Animation_Backdrop.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px #00000033 solid;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
.MSL-Splash-Content {
    padding: 20px 0px 40px 0px;
}
```

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="MSL-Splash-Section">
    <div class="MSL-Splash-Content">

        <!-- STUFF -->

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide site url ??

Comment: @AnzilkhaN. Yes: https://codepen.io/matie/pen/YemPyp

Answer (score 0):

Try to add 100vh in your css class like this:

```
.MSL-Splash-Section {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0px 20px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #FFF url(https://sephora.csod.com/clientimg/sephora/welcome/Animation_Backdrop.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px #00000033 solid;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    height:100vh;//Add 100vh
}
```

Comment: Although the background height fits with your solve, it doesn't cover as intended with this solution. Thew height gets cropped off. I need the background image to cover the entire div.

Comment: Add: background-position: center;

Comment: As it turns out, iOS devices don't support background images in shorthand CSS form. Also, I don't think iOS supports the background image "cover" property at all. See post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36686654/fixed-background-images-disappear-on-iphone-ipad

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

**iOS doesn't support shorthand CSS for background images that "cover" a section.**

**Answers:**

[Fixed background images disappear on iPhone/ iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36686654/fixed-background-images-disappear-on-iphone-ipad)

[Background image not showing on iPad and iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999660/background-image-not-showing-on-ipad-and-iphone)